# How to run a ./configure script inside makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu, configure, libpng

I have tried the following:

```
$(shell ./libpng/configure)
./libpng/configure
```

under this context

```
all : build_jpeg build_libpng

#JPEG BUILD RULES
build_jpeg :
        make -C ./jpeg  

#LIB PNG BUILD RULES
build_libpng :
        $(shell ./libpng/configure)
        make -C ./libpng
```

What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens when you just do `./libpng/configure`? Make sure the configure script is executable! (`chmod +x ./libpng/configure`)

Comment: lol forgot to check the file properties. Normally when you download a tar file it is usually executable. In this case I downloaded source from start team. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: The problem here is that the configure will generate the files on the parent directory and not inside the folder libpng.

Answer (score 1):

If you want configure to generate the files in the folder libpng you can:

`(cd ./libpng && ./configure)`

Code in parentheses is executed in  a  subshell.